# #1064 - Error when import database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

When I import database , i get these error:

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wppo_arf_ar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `frm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aweber` text NOT NULL,
  `mailchimp` text NOT NULL,
  `getresponse` text NOT NULL,
  `gvo` text NOT NULL,
  `ebizac` text NOT NULL,
  `icontact` text NOT NULL,
  `constant_contact` text NOT NULL,
  `enable_ar` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT='11'
```

**MySQL said:**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT='11'' at line 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AUTO_INCREMENT='11'
```

should be

```
AUTO_INCREMENT=11
```

Otherwise it thinks you're trying to use a string
Also as Damien said the engine type should be

```
Engine=MyISAM
```

Complete valid snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wppo_arf_ar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `frm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aweber` text NOT NULL,
  `mailchimp` text NOT NULL,
  `getresponse` text NOT NULL,
  `gvo` text NOT NULL,
  `ebizac` text NOT NULL,
  `icontact` text NOT NULL,
  `constant_contact` text NOT NULL,
  `enable_ar` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) Engine=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11
```

Comment: You must quote the author if you will use his code :)

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntaxis, MyISAM is the engine type of your table. On the other hand, String is not a Int, and AUTO_INCREMENT has type Int so, the final query looks like:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wppo_arf_ar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `frm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aweber` text NOT NULL,
  `mailchimp` text NOT NULL,
  `getresponse` text NOT NULL,
  `gvo` text NOT NULL,
  `ebizac` text NOT NULL,
  `icontact` text NOT NULL,
  `constant_contact` text NOT NULL,
  `enable_ar` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT = 11
```